# Downcast anyObject to String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working with Xcode6-Beta6 and want to display an item from an NSArray on the screen.

extract from code is as follows

```
    var task: AnyObject?  = categoriesForOption.valueForKey("task")!
    var taskName: UILabel = view.viewWithTag(10) as UILabel
    taskName.text         = task as? String
```

task contains (
    Tea
)
taskName contains nil

I've searched for solutions and found many answers, but none of them seem to work. The extract above is the nearest I've come to solving my problem.
Hope someone can help me as I'm banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant `NSDictionary` and not `NSArray`.

I think this way it's more explicit:

```
var task = categoriesForOption.valueForKey("task") as? String
```

Type inferral will make task a `String?` - it will be populated with a value if the value corresponding to the "task" key exists in the dictionary **and** if it's a string. It's `nil` otherwise.

Comment: Tried, but Task contains nil

Comment: Looking at your comment in @derdida's answer, task doesn't seem to be of `String` type. If you remove the `as? String` in my code above and put a breakpoint, can you figure out what's its actual type?

Comment: The data contained in the Array is from core data where Task is of type String. This is what Task contains after removing as? String Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x7f87636bc1d0>(
Groceries 
)

Comment: That seems to indicate that's an array and not a string

Comment: Thanks for that Antonio, I'm trying to rewrite an Objective_C App in Swift. I think I've got a little confused over things.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var task: String!  = String(categoriesForOption.valueForKey("task"))
taskName.text = task
```

Comment: tried, but get error Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'AnyObject?'

Comment: Can you post the Code for the init of your "categoriesForOption" Dictionary?

Comment: Categories for option (
    "<Task: 0x7fe57ac9ee40> (entity: Task; id: 0xd0000000004c0000 <x-coredata://A31FA04F-5CAA-4C67-A16F-F0A88F648338/Task/p19> ; data: {\n    alertid = 0;\n    category = \"Groceries \";\n    duedatetime = \"2014-08-26 20:34:05 +0000\";\n    repeatid = 0;\n    task = Tea;\n})"
)